# Is it possible to add user tracking method in EDM (Electronic direct mailer) Email click?

Tags: tracking, electronic-direct-mail

Here is the scenario:

We have designed an email template in which there are two option buttons:  "Yes"  &  "No". 
We send this email template to a group of user email lists.
After that, can we track the event where a recipient clicks on either the Yes button or No button.

1. which method can be used to track down how many of the recipients had clicked the Yes button or the No button?
2. how difficult is it to track the selected option Yes/No made by each single user?
3. which tracker is preferred: database tracker, google analytics tracker, mailchimp or other 3rd party web services?

Answer (score 0):

With Google Analytics, you can do manual campaign tagging where you assign specific query parameters to each button. The query parameters will track back to your Google Analytics data, and can tell you which buttons were clicked. This is an easy method as all you need to do is build specific URLs for each button, and then embed those URLs into the email template for each button.

Here is the URL Builder site: https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/1033867?hl=en

Comment: Furthermore, if using google analytics url builder, is it possible to identify the email template option button being clicked from which user email? @nyuen   I don't think it's possible cause javascript are ripped off whenever u send a edm( electronice direct mailer like mailchimp)